# Regex (for jQuery) to validate positive numbers with 2 decimal points

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, match

I need to match a field with regex using jQuery. Currently I am using:

```
 onsubmit: function (settings, td) {
            //select integers only
            var intRegex = /[0-9 -()+]+$/;
            var input = $(td).find('input');
            var original = input.val();

            if (original <= 0) {
                Alert('The amount should be bigger than 0');
                return false;
            }
            if (!original.match(intRegex)) {
                Alert('Please enter a valid number');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

A string like `"abc"` does not pass the check. But invalid characters like `@#$%` or `"/"` do pass the check, which causes an error in my method.

I am looking for regex which:

Matches: `1.20, 1, 2.00, 3.1`

Does not match: `-1.2, abc, 1/2, $, @#$%`

I browsed through the regex library, but if I put `(^\d*\.?\d*[0-9]+\d*$)|(^[0-9]+\d*\.\d*$)` inside my script, I get a syntax error...

Comment: Tip: This is a nice site for regexp testing: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
var intRegex = /^\d+(?:\.\d\d?)?$/;
```

That should work.

Comment: Do I need to add anything? cause i get syntax error if i put var intRegex = ^\d+(?:.\d\d)$;
Thanks!

Comment: See post edit, I included var initialization plus an error I had spotted

Comment: Thanks for your kind and quick help!

Answer (score 5):

Here's why you were getting false positives with your original regex:

```
/[0-9 -()+]+$/
     ^^^
```

The part I underlined forms a range from the space character (`U+0020`) to the left parenthesis (`U+0028`), making your regex equivalent to this:

```
/[0-9 !"#$%&'()+]+$/
```

If you want to match a hyphen, you either need to escape it with a backslash or place it at the beginning or end of the set, like so:

```
/[0-9 ()+-]+$/
```

Also, if by "the regex library" you mean RegExLib.com, I wouldn't trust any regex I found there.  The one you posted is a case in point:

```
/(^\d*\.?\d*[0-9]+\d*$)|(^[0-9]+\d*\.\d*$)/
```

First, it could have been written much more concisely:

```
/^(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.\d*)$/
```

Second, it matches strings like `123.` and `000000.0000000`, which you probably don't want.  If you really want to match only positive numbers, you have to make sure there's at least one non-zero digit in the string, either before or after the decimal point.  Here's one way to do that:

```
/^(?:[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d\d?)?|0\.[1-9]\d?|0\.0[1-9])$/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var regxp = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
```